Postgresql Return Empty {} for range_agg
When I am using range_agg() function, it works fine with original table value
Query Result
But when I try to do some update for range value, it will give back an empty list
Select range_agg(b.r)
From (
  Select int8range(lower(bin_range)+1, upper(bin_range)+5) as r 
  From bin_data) as b;

Query Result
All these query are running on pgAdmin4, wondering why it happens
I test with the same query in fiddle but no issue there
https://dbfiddle.uk/1MRn8hn6

Please update the post with the appropriate PostgreSQL version tag. I've run this with PostgreSQL v16.3, and pgAdmin-4 v8.8 and the reported issue does not occur.

Figure out the issue that there are empty ranges in our table and filter with
bin_range != 'empty'

Then everything get to work
